# Hotchocolate Strawberryshake how to use a mutation?

Tags: hotchocolate

There seem to be no examples at all on how to do a mutation by a graphql client using Strawberryshake (C#). Using Strawberryshake Version11.0.0-preview.138, Abstractions and Http v. 10.3.0-preview.12 and CodeGeneration.CSharp.Analyzers v. 0.0.30, I can run the query from the [example](https://chillicream.com/blog/2019/11/25/strawberry-shake_2) just fine. Now I added a mutation, but I can't figure how to use it?

I got the following from the schema import (Alarm.graphql):

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
  alarms: [Alarm]
}

type Mutation {
  addAlarm(input: AlarmInput): AlarmPayload
}

type AlarmPayload {
  alarm: Alarm
}

type Alarm {
  id: Int!
  handle: Int!
  messageId: Int!
  message: String
}

input AlarmInput {
  id: Int!
  handle: Int!
  messageId: Int!
  message: String
}
```

The query using

```
query getAlarms {
    alarms {
        message
    }
}
```

is just fine. For the mutation I added

```
mutation writeAlarm {
    addAlarm {
       alarm {
            id
            handle
            messageId
            message
        }
    }
}
```

Which successfully generates quite a lot of sensible looking classes on build. Now I create a connection to the server:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient(
"ConnectorLogGraphQL",
    c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/graphql"));
serviceCollection.AddAlarmClient();
var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
IAlarmClient client = services.GetRequiredService<IAlarmClient>();
```

The client is what I need to use. For the query, I can use:

```
var result = await client.GetAlarmsAsync();
```

similarly

```
var result = await client.WriteAlarmAsync();
```

compiles just fine, but of course it doesn't do what I'd like to. There's some WriteAlarmOperation defined, which I could pass as a parameter to WriteAlarmAsync, but this operation doesn't have fields for the input either. Something's missing.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit old now as I'm using StrawberryShake/HotChocolate 12.18.0 but I had some similar questions and issues.

Rather than passing in the full object into the mutation definition, I passed in a parameter so something like so:

```
mutation writeAlarm($alarm: AlarmInput) {
    addAlarm(input:$alarm) {
       alarm {
            id
            handle
            messageId
            message
        }
    }
}
```

The block here is the return object from the mutation and I believe to be optional:

```
alarm {
            id
            handle
            messageId
            message
        }
```

I think it's convention to return some information regarding the object you created as part of the return body so good to have this here.

I'm going to assume that this line is the syntax in SS10:

```
var result = await client.WriteAlarmAsync();
```

as the syntax in SS12 I'm using is:

```
var result = await client.WriteAlarms.ExecuteAsync(<input object>);
```

where in your case `<input object>` is an AlarmInput which you can generate via something like:

```
new AlarmInput()
            {
                Id = <someId>,
                Handle: <someHandle>,
                MessageId: <someMessageId>,
                Message: <someMessage>
            }
```

I think you can directly insert an object but I found that SS capitalises the properties so my solution so far has involved mapping fields unfortunately.